# Updating the content of the TransformedBitmap's source doesn't update the rendered picture

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to render live video feed from web camera. I'm trying to change the source of my Image object each time new frame arrived. I create WritableBitmap that is updated with new frame each time and TransformedBitmap that applies flip transformation on WritableBitmap as its source. If i create new TransformedBitmap for each frame it works and i see video feed, although the memory footprint is growing very fast, causing the GC to collect the memory very frequently. If i'm trying to reuse single TransformedBitmap I see no update on rendering, first frame is always displayed.

How can I reuse the same TransformedBitmap object without growth of the memory footprint?

Here is the sample code using two different files to emulate the web cam.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    Thread m_thread;
    BitmapImage source1;
    BitmapImage source2;
    byte[] data;
    int stride;
    WriteableBitmap bitmap;
    TransformedBitmap tb;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("1.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        source1 = new BitmapImage();
        source1.BeginInit();
        source1.StreamSource = stream;
        source1.EndInit();

        FileStream stream2 = new FileStream("2.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        source2 = new BitmapImage();
        source2.BeginInit();
        source2.StreamSource = stream2;
        source2.EndInit();

        stride = source1.PixelWidth * (source1.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
        data = new byte[stride * source1.PixelHeight];

        bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(source1.PixelWidth, source1.PixelHeight, source1.DpiX, source1.DpiY, source1.Format, source1.Palette);
        WritePixels(source1, bitmap, data);

        tb = new TransformedBitmap(bitmap, new ScaleTransform(-1, 1));

        m_thread = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
        m_thread.Start();
    }

    public void ThreadFunc()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                BitmapSource source = (i % 2 == 0) ? source2 : source1;
                WritePixels(source, bitmap, data);
                image1.Source = tb;
            }));
            ++i;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public void WritePixels(BitmapSource source, WriteableBitmap target, byte[] data)
    {
        int stride = source.PixelWidth * (source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);

        source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);
        target.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight), data, stride, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it, the problem was caused by the fact that the TransformedBitmap was the same so probably Image object didn't recognize the change, if I use two different TransformedBitmap objects that have the same source, and then after writing new content I switch the TransformedBitmap it works, I have new content rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it, the problem was caused by the fact that the TransformedBitmap was the same so probably Image object didn't recognize the change, if I use two different TransformedBitmap objects that have the same source, and then after writing new content I switch the TransformedBitmap it works, I have new content rendered.

So the code is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Thread m_thread;
    BitmapImage source1;
    BitmapImage source2;
    byte[] data;
    int stride;
    WriteableBitmap bitmap1;

    TransformedBitmap tb1;
    TransformedBitmap tb2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("1.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        source1 = new BitmapImage();
        source1.BeginInit();
        source1.StreamSource = stream;
        source1.EndInit();

        FileStream stream2 = new FileStream("2.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        source2 = new BitmapImage();
        source2.BeginInit();
        source2.StreamSource = stream2;
        source2.EndInit();

        stride = source1.PixelWidth * (source1.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
        data = new byte[stride * source1.PixelHeight];

        bitmap1 = new WriteableBitmap(source1.PixelWidth, source1.PixelHeight, source1.DpiX, source1.DpiY, source1.Format, source1.Palette);
        WritePixels(source1, bitmap1, data);

        tb1 = new TransformedBitmap(bitmap1, new ScaleTransform(-1, -1));
        tb2 = new TransformedBitmap(bitmap1, new ScaleTransform(-1, -1));

        m_thread = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
        m_thread.Start();
    }

    public void ThreadFunc()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                BitmapSource source = (i % 2 == 0) ? source2 : source1;
                WritePixels(source, bitmap1, data);
                // this is the trick we have to set different TransformedBitmap as
                // Image.Source
                // so since we don't want to create new one each time we just
                // switch between two
                image1.Source = (i % 2 == 0) ? tb1 : tb2;
            }));
            ++i;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public void WritePixels(BitmapSource source, WriteableBitmap target, byte[] data)
    {
        int stride = source.PixelWidth * (source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);

        source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);
        target.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight), data, stride, 0);
    }
}
```